# Drag an image on another image and save it to one image (like light augmented reality)

Tags: javascript, html, image, drag-and-drop

i´m wondering how can i realize this? I want to have an bigger image in the background and be able to drag and drop a smaller image to the position i want on the bigger image and save it finally, so it becomes one.

Is this possible with javascript & html5?

appreciate any ideas!

thanks

Answer (score 3):

For the drag an drop part you can just position one image on top of the other and give it some alpha-value to make it half-transparent:

```
#dragme {
    opacity:0.4;
}
```

the drag-and-drop you can do with jquery-ui:

```
$("#dragme").draggable();
```

try it out at:

http://jsfiddle.net/bjelline/k3vaX/

If you want to actually merge the two images to create a new
one use an image processing library, like pixatastic http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/blend/

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. i will try that, sounds good!, sorry can´t give you +1, cause i´m under 15 reputation

Comment: How can i merge it with pixastic? Can´t find the right function :D

Comment: The link goes to "blend" - isn't that what you want to do?

Comment: So i just have to blend the smaller image with the bigger with an amount of "1"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, when you have your images in position:

- Create a canvas element the size of the background image
- Draw your background image into it
- Iterate through your images and record positions
- Draw each image by using the Canvas' context.drawImage(image, posX, posY) that you recorded
- Extract the final image from Canvas using canvas.toDataUrl()

The data url can be set as src on the background image or you can upload it directly to a server etc. Setting it to an image allow you to right-click it and use Save as.

If you initially use the canvas as the "background" image (covering the window) - you just initialize it with the image you want in the background, then continue from point three above.

Comment: i guess pixastic is using the canvas to do this rigth? Thanks for the reply!Still only 11 reputation, so cant give u +1 :(

Comment: @MarcSter I'm not familiar with pixastic, but this is the only "low-level" way of doing it directly in HTML5 using Javascript so I would guess so. The other option is to send everything to a server and process it there (or using a Flash based application).

Comment: I understand the instructions, but don´t know how to mix it up with the right code :/ could you post a fiddle of the upper instructions? That would be so great! I´m a beginner in javascript and especially in canvas.. feel a bit lost right now